# Different Types of Web Services

Tags: java, ajax, wcf, web-services

I developed a mobile application using PhoneGap, to connect to a database through a web service. Since, I am familiar with the .NET environment, I used a WCF service, or more specifically an Ajax Enabled WCF Service, so that I could call the web service through an Ajax call.

Now, I am an absolute beginner in web services and I don't even know the difference between REST and SOAP web services and whether this Ajax Enable WCF service is SOAP or REST web service. Also, can I develop the same web service using Java?

Can you please recommend a book or a tutorial where I can have a crash course on web services and find an answer for all these questions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web service is simply a definition for how two logically or otherwise separated systems can communicate. REST and SOAP are simply two protocols in which this communication can occur. Think of it in terms of a human language wherein one language requires about 100 syllables to get a message across to a listener while another language allows you pass the same message across in 75 syllables or less.

From the metaphor above, REST will be the slimmer 75 syllable language and SOAP the more elaborate 100+ syllabic language. 
Note that the transport mechanism remains the same ( oral or spoken word) which is the same case with web services, I.e. the same protocol (REST or SOAP) can be transmitted over different transport channels http, low level sockets, SMTP etc. You can have an overview [here](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp)

At the end of the day, the founding principle of web services is interoperability, enabling disparate and technologically different systems communicate via open protocols in a platform agnostic manner. Meaning your WCF based service will basically be able to do the same thing as a java(JAX-WS or RS) web service albeit they'll go about it differently.

Comment: Thanks. That explained it really well. But, what type of service is the Ajax Enabled WCF service? REST or SOAP? And are there more protocols apart from REST and SOAP please?

Comment: @user1135357 you're welcome. Just think of REST and SOAP as text formats and then you can, in theory, use any other formatting scheme (CSV,XML) to transmit data over a webservice, as long as both parties involved in the exchange have agreed to the formatting. I'm not a .NET person, but I'm pretty sure it's going to be REST-based, as REST is the de facto standard for AJAX calls. SOAP will simply be  too heavy in AJAX